# Is there a rule for forming the diminutive of names?

Tags: diminutivos, nombres-propios

In Spanish, the diminutive form of names can be used to affectionately refer to someone. Are there any rules for how to derive the diminutive form of names (of people, not places), or is it different on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Do you mean the name of a person or names in general?

Comment: @Laura: The name of a person, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: You mean using `Ale` rather than `Alejandro(a)` for example?

Comment: @César: That would be shortening or abbreviation, rather than diminutive. I guess that's what the OP is pointing at, though.

Comment: So, `Alejandrito` rather than `Alejandro`. This is a tough one

Comment: @César: Yes, diminutives, not nicknames. So Alejandrito instead of Alejandro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If the name ends in a vowel but no "I":
>
> *eliminate the vowel and add "ito/illo/ín/iño" (male) or "ita/illa/ina/iña" (female).*

- Eduardo - Eduardito/Eduardillo/Eduardín/Eduardiño
- Manolo - Manolito/Manolillo/Manolín/Manoliño
- Mirta - Mirtita/Mirtilla/Mirtina/Mirtiña
- Marco - Marquito/Marquillo/Marquín/Marquiño
- Carlo - Carlito/Carlillo/Carlín/Carliño
- Carla - Carlita/Carlilla/Carlina/Carliña

**Exception:** *a woman name ended in "O". Add "ito".*

- Rocío - Rociito.

> If the name ends in a consonant or "I":
>
> *add "cito/"cillo/ciño" or "cita/cilla/ciña".*

- Javier - Javiercito/Javiercillo/Javiercín/Javierciño
- Germán - Germancito/Germancillo/Germancín/Germanciño
- Lilian - Liliancita/Liliancilla/Lilianciña
- Marlon - Marloncito/Marloncillo/Marloncín/Marlonciño
- Pati - Paticita/Paticilla/Paticiña
- Pili - Pilicita/Pilicilla/Piliciña

**Note**: I'm not sure, but if the name ends in "I", don't use "cina", it sounds very bad and I've never heard it.

**Two exceptions:**

1. *names ended in "L". Add "ito/illo/ín/iño" or "ita/illa/ina/iña".*

   - Isabel - Isabelita/Isabelilla/Isabelina/Isabeliña
   - Mabel - Mabelita/Mabelilla/Mabelina/Mabeliña
   - Raquel - Raquelita/Raquelilla/Raquelina/Raqueliña
   - Rafael - Rafaelito/Rafaelillo/Rafaelín/Rafaeliño
2. *names ended in "s" (irregulars?).*

   - Carlos - Carlitos (also Carlín, Carliño, Carlillos)
   - Marcos - Marquitos (also Marquín, Marquiño, Marquillos)
   - Andrés - Andrecito (also Andrecín, Andreciño, Andrecillo)

Comment: Hola Ricardo, I tried to improve your formatting to make your answer look more schematic. If you don't like it, feel free to improve it or rollback :)

Comment: Me hubiera gustado que quedara así desde el inicio, ¡gracias!

Comment: Muy bien. :) ¡De nada!

Comment: +1 Muy buena respuesta!

Comment: Raquel no lleva tilde.

Comment: @CesarGon Lo he cambiado, pero en mi experiencia práctica en el registro civil te ponen el nombre como quieras :). La Raquél que conozco lo tiene con tilde en el DNI.

Comment: Manolo ya es apodo de Manuel.

Answer (score 0):

There are only rules of diminutives such as `-cito` or `-ito`. But for personal names, there are no rules. Since such nicknames were created by children as stammer words Apensen know. An example is the name of `Rodolfo` is `Fito` and `Felipe` is `Pipe`.

Comment: I actually was asking about diminutives such as *-ito* and *-cito*, not nicknames like *Fito* (see comments above).

Comment: In fact the vast majority of personal names he has a nickname, and is classified as a diminutive and not as a nickname